# Where should I ask about a text font used somewhere?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

Is there any SE site where I can ask users tell me/help me find what the font used in some media (movie, picture, whatever) is? If so, which one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) has a [font-identification tag](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info); read its guidance. It suggests trying automatic font recognition tools like [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) first.

Graphic Design’s [help center](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and the tag info link to this meta question about font identification questions: [What are the requirements for font identification questions?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1083).

To summarize: you need to show your efforts (e.g. with the tools from the tag guidance), give as much details as possible about the font (source, screenshot, etc.), and make your question title specific.